# Atom, Flow, Nuclide: Cannot resolve module (with React Native)

Tags: react-native, npm, atom-editor, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I'm new to Flow. I just started using Nuclide and Flow. I want to use it with React Native.

**TLDR:** When I try to run `npm run flow` I get the following errors:

```
... 47 more errors (only 50 out of 97 errors displayed)
To see all errors, re-run Flow with --show-all-errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! albums@0.0.1 flow: `flow`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the albums@0.0.1 flow script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jan/.npm/_logs/2018-06-25T20_02_13_257Z-debug.log
```

Here is what I did step by step:

1. I started a new react native app using `react-native init albums` and switched to in the new folder (`cd albums`).
2. Next I ran ([according to the flow guide](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/)) `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-flow`, which gave me the following output:

   npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

   - babel-cli@6.26.0
   - babel-preset-flow@6.23.0
     added 22 packages from 16 contributors in 7.711s
     [!] 2 vulnerabilities found [71756 packages audited]
     Severity: 1 Low | 1 High
     Run `npm audit` for more detail
3. I then ran `npm install --save-dev flow-bin`.
4. Then I ran `npm run flow init`. This gives the error: `npm ERR! missing script: flow`, so I add `"flow": "flow"` to my scripts and run `npm run flow init` again getting the error: `Error: "/Users/jan/Dev/react-native/albums/.flowconfig" already exists!`.
5. So I run `npm run flow`. This throws the error:

   Launching Flow server for /Users/jan/Dev/react-native/albums
   Wrong version of Flow. The config specifies version ^0.67.0 but this is version 0.75.0
   Could not start Flow server!
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 78
   npm ERR! albums@0.0.1 flow: `flow`
   npm ERR! Exit status 78
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the albums@0.0.1 flow script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /Users/jan/.npm/_logs/2018-06-25T20_11_22_239Z-debug.log

   6. After some googling I found out that I have to delete my `.flowconfig and run`npm run flow init again`, which is what I did. This is successful, so I run`npm run flow`. Now I get the error:

   ... 47 more errors (only 50 out of 97 errors displayed)
   To see all errors, re-run Flow with --show-all-errors
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 2
   npm ERR! albums@0.0.1 flow: `flow`
   npm ERR! Exit status 2
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the albums@0.0.1 flow script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /Users/jan/.npm/_logs/2018-06-25T20_15_18_952Z-debug.log

This is where I'm stuck now, and I can't get this to work.